# FullPage2.0.7 problems on rotation / fullpage sections get triple on android

Tags: jquery, html, mobile, rotation, fullpage.js

I've a homepage of a website managed with fullpage (actually in progress, so not published).
I've this code to initialize the fullpage library

```
$('#eg_homepage').fullpage({
    anchors: this.hFullpageAnchors,
    slidesColor: this.hFullpageSlideColors,
    navigation: true,
    navigationPosition: 'right',
    navigationTooltips: this.hFullpageNavigationTooltips,
    navigationColor: '#697681',
    verticalCentered: false,
    resize:false,
    scrollingSpeed:500,
    scrollOverflow: true,
    afterLoad: function(anchorLink, index){ ... },
    afterRender:function(){ ... },
    onLeave:function(index, nextIndex, direction){ ... }
});
```

Unluckily I can't link the website.
These are the libraries included in the html

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='js/modernizr.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='js/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.js'></script> <!-- used for fullpage / slider -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.slimscroll.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='js/jquery.fullPage.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='js/jquery.validate.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='js/jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='js/home.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='js/scripts.js'></script>
```

I can give you some details:

- there are around 9 sections
- there are some accordions
- a jquery ui slider
- css animations

the problem is that when i rotate from **VERT** to *HORIZ* on the smartphone, everything is resized correctly. when I rotate it back from **HORIZ** to **VERT** the fullpage is not resized correctly, and three sections turn visible, the current one is the first of the three on top. from this scenario i can still scroll up and down, but just displaying three sections per time. Rotating again to **HORIZ** makes the app work fine, and **VERT** still with three sections per time.
any idea? thanks

Comment: Which version of fullpage.js are you using? Which smartphone?

Comment: I'm using fullPage 2.0.7

Comment: The mobile i'm dealing are Samsung Galaxy Nexus / Samsung S4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download the latest version of fullpage.js ( 2.1.8)  (and its css file)

The problem you are talking about was solved in 2.1.6 as you can see in the [github issues of fullpage.js plugin](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/pull/542).

[Here's the issue](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/issues/248) treated it in its forum.

Comment: it will take some time to test, because just updating the `jquery.fullPage.css` and the `jquery.fullPage.min.js`, `jquery.slimscroll.min.js` files, makes everything is not working anymore, the sliding from a full section to another is blocked.

Comment: I need to update even the HTML. I'll make a quick test about it.

Comment: It should be working properly. Make sure you are not caching any of those files. There has been changes in all of them.

Comment: Check the javascript console to detect errors. One of them might be that  you are using the old callback for `onLeave`, which now includes a new parameter `nextIndex`.

Comment: I'm facing issues on HTML, class and id names, html tags (involving even my code). now it's almost everything working.

Comment: When you have it working it would be nice if you accept the answer in case anybody else has the same problem and end up here.

Comment: Everything works fine after refactoring tags, classes and ids.